# For J2EE project to run on different Computer what does it need?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I know for a Java Program to run on another Computer it needs JRE(Java Runtime Environment). But for a J2EE application (Serlvet-JSP) or Struts2 framework application or Hibernate framework application or any Framework application of Java what are need to Run it Successfully on another computer where it is not developed....
I know JRE is required for both type of Application. and JDK is for developing an application.

I also know that for Mobile application to run on device it needs an Emulator that supports the particular OS (Android, iOS, etc). Just like an Standalone Java Application.

But for running J2EE application is there any other requirements than JRE??

For Example:- I have made a site called SocialMash.com I want to have a working prototype to deliver to user (User meaning like we all use Stackoverflow and other sites). What will I require to configure the site.

I know I will require a server like Tomcat/JBOSS/GlassFish but that all will be on my side (server side/ development side) but Do the Users to use the site will require anything among JDK, JRE, Server, or anything to use SocialMash.com or just URL will be enough?????

Comment: and the libraries you use in your application. Hopefully you have a build tool like maven, gradle. If not put your libraries into you servers lib/ext folder, zip the server and distribute it to your developers

Answer (score 1):

A J2EE project intends to create a web service. In order to run this project on your computer, you need a local server.

Any IDE can provide you a local server like Tomcat or Glassfish, you just need to try to run this project to get these options.

If you don't need to access the code on the other computer, two options:

- You compile your project to get a .war file, which you can deploy on your Tomcat server, or any else.
- You put this on a server of yours, and share the url.

Assuming that you are in charge of the app hosting:

- If that the app is running on your own **remote server**, you just need to share the app url and your user can access it with his browser (nothing more is needed).
- If you run it in your own computer, as **localhost**, he won't be able to access it, and I recommand the usage of a host like [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) to make it accessible (that's a free solution).

Comment: Just added informations about app hosting, hoping that's what you'r looking for. ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a JavaEE application server. It runs on top of JRE. You can check this open-source reference implementation (full-profile, my favourite):

https://glassfish.java.net/

or if you want to have only web-profile:

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

Web profile is different from full profile in that web profile supports only Servlet-JSP, but not JPA (or hibernate as stated in your question).

Users will not require anything except for the browser in case you    write a web application (Servlets+JSP, Struts, JSF, etc. - just give them a web reference). But you can go further than that. You can    write a Java SE desktop client for EJB, or SOAP service (they will be placed in full-profile server like Glassfish), and distribute for your    customers. In this way they will not require any browser, but your    custom desktop program.

Some of the libraries require to be added to your application server and configured manually. Like Struts. In this case you first need to decide which framework/library you would like to use, then go to their web site, and follow the tutorial on its installation.

Answer (score 1):

To host an J2EE application, a webserver is required that has **servlet container**. servers included in XAMPP/LAMP/WAMPP will do for php based application. But for J2EE application servlet container is rquired which is there in **TOMCAT/GLASSFISH/JBOSS.**

On the **user side**, the user sees **pure HTML** with additional js/css. He does not see the jsp scriplets/servlet code written in your J2EE application. so **no java technology is required on the user** system. He only needs a browser.